# Unexpected results for large-offset-n in Foundation for Email v2.2

Tags: zurb-foundation, html-email

I am trying to have four single column width columns on large screens which are in the centre of the screen. I am using large-offset-4 to offset these columns by the equivalent of 4 columns but the positioning of these columns comes out quite a bit further to the right and the first column is larger than a single column should be.

I am running v2.2.1 of foundation for emails, the Sass version writing in Inky I have attempted multiple things but there appears to be some additional margin on the image in the first column which I haven't been able to override in sass. Everything looks as expected on small screens but on large the columns are not showing correctly. According to _grid.scss:101 the width of th.large-1 should be 32.33333px but it is displaying at 126.672px for the first column and 59px for all other columns.

```
<wrapper style="background: #ffffff">
<container>
    <row>
        <columns small="12" large="12" valign="middle" style="background: #ffffff;">
            <h2 class="text-center">Connect with us</h2>
        </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columns small="2" large="1"  style="background: #ffffff;" class="large-offset-4 small-offset-2">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Like us on Facebook." style="max-width: 40px; height: auto;"></a>
        </columns>
        <columns small="2" large="1" style="background: #ffffff;" class="">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter." style="max-width: 40px; height: auto;"></a>
        </columns>
        <columns small="2" large="1" style="background: #ffffff;" class="">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" title="Find us on YouTube." style="max-width: 40px; height: auto;"></a>
        </columns>
        <columns small="2" large="1" style="background: #ffffff;" class="">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" title="Follow us on Instagram." style="max-width: 40px; height: auto;"></a>
        </columns>                                  
    </row>
    <row>
        <columns small="1" large="1" valign="middle" class="large-offset-3">
            <p><a href="tel:1800067066"><img src="assets/img/phone.png" style="max-width: 35px; height: auto;"></a></p>
        </columns>
        <columns small="5" large="2" valign="middle">
            <p class="text-center"><a href="tel:1800067066">1800 067 066</a></p>
        </columns>
        <columns small="1" large="1" valign="middle">
            <p class="text-right"><a href="mailto:"><img src="assets/img/email.png" style="max-width: 35px; height: auto;"></a></p>
        </columns>
        <columns small="4" large="2" valign="middle">
            <p class="text-center"><a href="mailto:">Email us</a></p>
        </columns>
    </row>
</container>
```

Lines 9 - 22 should be producing four columns that are a single column wide that is offset by 4 columns (essentially centring them on twelve column grid) Each column should contain a small image (max-width of 40px) wrapped in an  tag. Instead, the first column is about 4 columns wide and the content of it are in the centre of the screen, then all other columns are around 50px wide and to the right of the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my memory serves, the row needs to contain a total of 12 columns (including any offset).

so `.large-1`*2 + `.large-2`*2 + `.large-offset-3` = 9 columns

Try taking up the last 3 columns on the right with an empty column of `.large-3` to = 12